Is there any way to use nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.6.3 in Android Java?
I was using nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.3.2 in my Android java project for a while now.
But due to Play Store restriction on API version I had to update the SdkVersion to below.
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34

After updating this the ImagePicker stopped working because of the permission issue.
I have updated the permission as below.
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

Even after these changes the ImagePicker did not seem to be working and I had to update the library version to below
dependencies {
    // implementation 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.6.3'
}

After updating the library my old code stopped working and started giving the error.
ImagePicker.with(this).setToolbarColor("#2196f3").setStatusBarColor("#6F7A92").setToolbarTextColor("#FFFFFF").setToolbarIconColor("#FFFFFF").setProgressBarColor("#ff5d3b").setBackgroundColor("#ffffff").setMultipleMode(true).setFolderMode(true).setShowCamera(false).setFolderTitle("Choose Image").setLimitMessage("Select only 1 photo").setMaxSize(1).setSavePath("Photo Compressor").setAlwaysShowDoneButton(false).setRequestCode(100).setKeepScreenOn(true).start();

When I checked the documentation, the library was changed from Java to Kotlin.
https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker
After lot of research, I implemented the below code
ImagePickerConfig imagePickerConfig = new ImagePickerConfig();
imagePickerConfig.setImageTitle("Select Image");
ImagePickerKt.registerImagePicker(this, images).launch(imagePickerConfig);

But now I am getting the below error.
error: no suitable method found for registerImagePicker(ArrayList<Image>)
        ImagePickerKt.registerImagePicker(images).launch(imagePickerConfig);
                     ^
    method ImagePickerKt.registerImagePicker(ComponentActivity,Function0<? extends Context>,Function1<? super ArrayList<Image>,Unit>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImagePickerKt.registerImagePicker(Fragment,Function0<? extends Context>,Function1<? super ArrayList<Image>,Unit>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)


See this: https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker/issues/152
More friendly Java API support is available here, but it has not been merged: https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker/pull/160
